# jQuery get the id value from the matching attribute value

Tags: jquery, html

I have my markup like this

```
    <div class="content">
    <div class="star">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#" id="star2" data-id="123">Test1</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="star">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#" id="star2" data-id="123">Test1</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="star">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#" id="star3" data-id="890">Test1</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="star">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#" id="star7" data-id="543">Test1</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="star">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#" id="star9" data-id="876">Test1</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>                              
</div>
```

Now you can see for each `li` there is a `data-product-id` and `id`. Now lets say I want to get the id if `li` whose `data-product-id` is 876. Then it should show me id `star9`.

So for that I have made my code like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.star').each(function() {
        jQuery('[data-product-id="876"]').attr('id');
    });
});
</script>
```

But here I am not getting the id whose value is star9.
So what is the wrong with this part? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable.

Answer (score 2):

Why you loop over all the element with `.start` class ? Why not just do `jQuery('[data-product-id="876"]').attr('id');`, if your use case like that, try following code :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.star').each(function(i, e) {

    if ($(e).find('[data-id="876"]').length > 0)
      console.log($(e).find('[data-id="876"]').attr('id'));

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="star">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#" id="star2" data-id="123">Test1</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="star">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#" id="star2" data-id="123">Test1</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="star">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#" id="star3" data-id="890">Test1</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="star">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#" id="star7" data-id="543">Test1</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="star">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#" id="star9" data-id="876">Test1</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm with Norlihazmey, I don't see why you would have to loop over everything.

```js
$(function() {
  console.log($('[data-id="876"]').prop('id'))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="star">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#" id="star2" data-id="123">Test1</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="star">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#" id="star2" data-id="123">Test1</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="star">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#" id="star3" data-id="890">Test1</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="star">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#" id="star7" data-id="543">Test1</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="star">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#" id="star9" data-id="876">Test1</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```